# *Why* do ISPs block traffic on specific ports?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, port, openssh, isp

I've went down a rabbit hole after discovering that I couldn't ssh into a machine while on Starbucks WiFi (don't ask).

I've read about how to get around it, which ports are blocked, but not *why* port 22 (in this case) is blocked.

Why would this commonly used port be blocked by Google Fiber? At a place where it turns out (after research) a ton of developers do their developing at these locations?

Comment: that sound more that starbucks is blocking it, and why should'nt they? they give you access for browsing and try to make sure that no malicious activity is started from within their network.

Answer (score 1):

ISPs wisely optimize for the general case, and the general user is not savvy enough to protect their devices from attacks on well-known ports.

Blocking the most-attacked ports such as SSH (22) and the SMB & NetBIOS ports is the right thing to do on behalf of most customers.

For residential ISPs, it would be nice if they could have an opt-out if you want a completely unfiltered wild-west connection (maybe it could be an option if you're paying for a static public IPv4 address).

Answer (score 0):

A StarBucks or any other public venue is afraid of visitors doing Bad Things,
 including but not limited to cracking into other computer systems, pirating movies, using all available bandwidth so that other visitors can't use it, or distributing pornography.  StarBucks in general does not want to be involved in that.  The workers at the local StarBucks don't want to police it.  The management of the local StarBucks doesn't want to track down who's doing it.

Thus, since SSH can be used to do Bad Things, and it's easily blocked, the easiest way to do it is just block port 22.  Same for torrents on port 6881-6889 (and 6969).  It's easy to block all ports except 80 and 8080 for regular web page access.

Calling a venue an "ISP" is a distortion of the venue's purpose.  StarBucks is there to sell coffee, and offering slow generic web page access is just a come-on, which they are entitled to take away or limit at any time.  Whether a public library, a restaurant, or any other venue, it's not their responsibility to help anyone do crime.  And they need to protect themselves from visitors who want to do crime.  There's a tradeoff between losing legitimate services (your SSH) and stopping unknown bad visitors from performing bad actions.